# is it possible to open files in subdirectories with less?

Tags: wildcards, less

I sometimes use less to quickly page through a small collection of files using something like

```
less brscan/*/*
```

and then I use `:n` to cycle through the files

If I have a folder/s e.g.

```
brscan/
├── DEBIAN
│   ├── conffiles
│   ├── control
│   ├── postinst
│   ├── postrm
│   └── prerm
├── etc
│   └── opt
├── opt
│   └── brother
└── usr
    ├── bin
    └── lib64
```

in this example `less` will pick up the files in folder `DEBIAN`

```
DEBIAN
       ├── conffiles
       ├── control
       ├── postinst
       ├── postrm
       └── prerm
```

but it wont descend into other subdirectories, it just errors:

> brscan/etc is a directory
>   brscan/opt is a directory
>   brscan/usr is a directory

is it possible to get less to page the files in these subdirectories?

Im thinking something like

```
find brscan/ | xargs less
```

but its not working - still picking up directories

Comment: Something like this `find brscan/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 less` ?

Comment: works! I left out the `-print0` and the  `-0` option in xargs                   i.e.  `find brscan/ -type f | xargs less` thanks!

Comment: Great! There is a note about `-print0` and `-0` in the man page of `xargs` and explained why you should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify `-not -type d` to omit directories from the find result

```
find -not -type d | xargs less
```

or better:

```
find -not -type d -print0 | xargs -0 less
```

which handles filenames with spaces in them better.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`, [globstar](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) option enable, you can:

```
shopt -s globstar
less brscan/**/*
```

But it also includes directories. With `zsh`, you can filter expansion to regular files only:

```
less brscan/**/*(.)
```

All of the above will fail if too many files return. The safe way is using `find`:

```
find brscan -type f -exec less {} +
```

Comment: I should have mentioned Im using bash. yes `find brscan -type f -exec less {} +` works nice ! but I dont understand the compound expression `-exec less {} +`. does the `-exec` tell bash to execute `less`?

Comment: @user4668401: See https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files